# Two browsers, two internet connections, eth0 and wlan0

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, proxy

I would like to use both eth0 and wlan0 at the same time in different browsers.(say eth0 for Firefox and wlan0 for Chrome).
Requests to eth0 should be governed by a proxy server and the wlan0 should be normal. 
Could you suggest me how to do this?
P.S: some of the websites are blocked by the proxy server, so I would like to use wlan0 for browsing those, and the rest using eth0